# Spotify API error for searching songs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, spotify

I am doing a project where I want to search for songs using the Spotify API, but when I try to search for the song, this error comes up:

> [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 () https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=&type=track

This is a code snippet:

```
getSearchResults(query){
    const access_token = this.state.token;
    const searchQuery = query;
    console.log("Search Query: " + searchQuery.toString())
    const fetchURL = encodeURI(`q=${searchQuery}`);
    fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?${fetchURL}&type=track`,{
        method: "GET",
        headers:{
            Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
        }
    }
```

Has somebody had a similar error and know how to fix it? Would be much appreciated.

Comment: Error 401 means unauthorized. Are you sure that the token is valid? it might expire by the time you make the call.

Comment: Check your token

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you either have an expired token or the token is not genereated properly, Kindly follow the below steps to generate a new one.

**Step 1:** Go to spotify dashboard [https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard](https://Click%20here)

**Step 2:** Create a new **App**

**Step 3:** Copy client id and client secret

**Step 4:** Run the following command in terminal or do a post request through fetch or postman.

*(don't forget to replace your client_id and client_secret)*

```
curl -X POST "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>&client_secret=<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>"
```

You will recieve an output like

```
{
"access_token":"BQBu7....30HCnV-T8",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":3600
}
```

Copy this access token and use it in your request.